# Do numerical MHD codes contain particles?

Tags: astrophysics, computational-physics, simulations, plasma-physics, magnetohydrodynamics

Does an MHD code contain charged particles, or does one just numerically solve the MHD equations? Also, can you suggest a good introductory book/paper to learn the basics of MHD codes?

Comment: There are a variety of codes out there. PIC (particle in a cell) codes use, well, particles in cells…

Comment: @JonCuster Thanks! I know how PIC codes work but to my understanding, MHD codes are different than PIC.

Comment: Consider to spell out acronyms.

Comment: There are also MHD SPH (smoothed-particle hydrodynamics) codes — e.g., https://github.com/danieljprice/phantom — though I’m pretty sure that involves “solving the MHD equations”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do numerical MHD codes contain particles?

No, [magnetohydrodynamic (MHD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetohydrodynamics) codes do not contain particles.  They are fluid simulations and so only track velocity moments.  In an ideal MHD simulation, the plasma is treated as a single fluid.  In Hall MHD, the simulation can be written with two fluids, ions and electrons.

> Does an MHD code contain charged particles, or does one just numerically solve the MHD equations?

Well yes, an MHD code does solve the MHD equations but it's not a trivial thing to do.  The code is resolved on a user-defined mesh/grid.  The programmers need to do a lot of things to avoid flux pile-up, energy conservation, etc.

> Also, can you suggest a good introductory book/paper to learn the basics of MHD codes?

A good reference on the merger between particle-in-cell (PIC) and fluid MHD codes can bef ound at:
https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2014JCoPh.276..468W/abstract

Here are some decent starting points (and references therein) on MHD codes:

- https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2005JCoPh.208..315M/abstract
- https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1981JCoPh..43..357R/abstract
- https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1995ApJ...442..228R/abstract